# Brute force algorithm and string matching?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm really confused with how to do the following:

> Your main program should read in two strings from the user (one string at a time, so you will have two separate strings).  The first line (string) that is read is called the text string, and the second line (string) is called the pattern string.
>
> Then you will implement a function, called *match* that implements the simple brute force pattern matching.  This function takes two strings (the text string and the pattern string), and returns `True` if the pattern string matches some portion of the text string: otherwise, the function returns `False`.
>
> Your main program must keep doing the following task: ask the user for a text string and a pattern string and print a message that states whether the pattern was found in the text or not. The program stops when the user enters *qqq* as the text string (your program must stop regardless of the case of the letter).

So far, none of the codes I've typed out work. Please help me!

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: We're not going to just give you your homework answers. Do you have a specific question you could ask us? Some particular aspect of the problem that doesn't work the way you think it should? Some particular part of your code that behaves differently from how your mental model says it should work?

Comment: def bruteMatch (n,m):
    for i in range(0,len(n)-len(m)+1):
        if n[i:len(m)+1]==m:
            return (i)
n= "HelloStudents"
m= "Students"

if len(n) == len(m) then check n == m
else if len(n) > len(m) then return check m is in [ n[0:len(m)], .., n[0:len(n)] ]
else if len(n) < len(m) then Error: Invalid range

I didn't include my code in the question because it doesn't work. I just don't know how to get the thing to run and match...

Comment: Please add your code *in* the question.

Comment: Your code is hard to read-- edit your question and add it in there, formatted, etc. The `in` operator can be used in Python to tell if one string is contained in another, so `"foo" in "foobar"` will return `True`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've written up a pretty helpful program that might help you out. As @Scovetta mentioned, we can use Python's `in` operator. However, if you're adamant on using a brute force method and not using Python's nice syntactic sugar, then you can definitely do that.

Here is an example program I wrote up. Let me know if this helps! Feel free to ask any questions that you might have.

```
# This program is just going to find if a string contains a substring

def match(text, pattern):
    '''
    Simple match program
    '''
    if pattern in text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

test_cases = [['ab', 'bab'], ['cat', 'catdog'], ['banana', 'apple'], ['tree', 'tree']]

def brute_match(text,pattern):
    '''
    We just want to check that our text has our pattern
    So let's just iterate over our text
    '''
    length_of_pattern = len(pattern)
    for i in range(len(text)):
        # Abuse python's splicing because we don't have to worry about end of the string nonsense 
        if text[i:length_of_pattern+i] == pattern:
            return True
    return False


for case in test_cases:
    ans = match(case[1], case[0])
    bans = brute_match(case[1], case[0])
    print("{} is in {} (T/F): {}".format(case[0], case[1], ans))
    print("{} is in {} (T/F): {}".format(case[0], case[1], bans))


# Enter your main program 
# We want to loop infinitely unless we get qqq
while True:
    text_string = raw_input("Please enter your text string: ")
    if text_string == 'qqq':
        break
    pattern_string = raw_input("Please enter your pattern string: ")
    print("Using 'in' operator:")
    print('-'*20)
    if match(text_string):
        print("IS a valid match")
    else:
        print("NOT a valid match")
    print("Using brute force:")
    print('-'*20)
    if brute_match(text_string):
        print("IS a valid match")
    else:
        print("NOT a valid match")
```

I realize the code is a bit messy, but I just wanted to write it up quick for ya!

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I'm trying to write a text and a pattern, and then the program should find out if the pattern is in the text by shifting once over each time until there is a match. I'm a little confused with your code- what are the test cases and how come there are 4 of them? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Absolutely! Let me clear my code up a bit.

I created the test cases just for my own sanity. I wanted to prove that both cases were equivalent (or at least give myself a little double check). This is the reason I've created some sample test cases off the top of my head.

As for the `brute_match` algorithm, this is the algorithm that you describe. Python's string splicing does not allow for out of index bounds errors, so if we have `a = 'abc'`, then a[2:100] is STILL just 'c'. So i was abusing that nice convention. But the brute force algorithm is doing just that.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I'm a little confused on the ending. What's in operator and *20? Is there a way to run the code without those?

Comment: @user2357112 hey! I wasn't trying to do their homework / I didn't know that we couldn't do hw on stack. I'll refrain in the future. However, I think it should be noted that if the OP was solely looking for the answers, he wouldn't be asking follow ups. They are trying to learn which I think is great.

Comment: @MarkMason hey yeah. So the in operator is a python convention. It can be used in multiple different ways but essentially checks to see if something is IN something else. The *20 just makes twenty dashes. You can multiply strings by integers to create copies. Another great perk of python

Comment: Also, do you know how to fix the error "match takes at least 2 arguments, but 1 was given?" I've been trying to fix it by switching it to search and deleting it and whatnot, but nothing works.

Comment: I really am trying to learn, I struggle with this class, so I appreciate this a lot.  By the way, I'm not stealing your code, I'm just using it as an example! But yeah, I've tried match, search, re.search, etc. and I'm always getting an error match() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) :(

Comment: @MarkMason yeah absolutely! Sorry that's a bug in my code. You want it match(text_string, pattern_string) on the line with if statement. Absolutely would love to help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a lifesaver!